# Is it possible send from multiaddress using single transaction without contract?

Tags: ether, parity, json-rpc

Is it possible send from multiaddress using single transaction without Smart contract?

I have read somewhere, using https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_signtransaction (signTransaction) you can create multiple address to send single transaction. But I m not aware about it. Can you help me on it?

Comment: What does "multiaddress" mean?

Comment: Also, "I have read somewhere" <-- where? Please link to what you read.

Comment: MultiAddress means Can I use more then one address in "From" Parameter?

Comment: No, the `from` address is a single address.

Comment: Then How to send multiple from address using single transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the clarifications in comments:

- No, you can't send a transaction from multiple addresses. It's always from one address
- No, you can't send a transaction to multiple addresses. It's always to one address. A smart contract can issue multiple transactions to send to multiple addresses.

So, one transaction is from one address to one address.

Comment: Then how third party are managing multiaddress send in single transaction as like Cryptonator? @lauri-peltonen

Comment: I have no idea what Cryptonator is. What makes you think they do it in a single transaction? And the term 'transaction' in this context refers to a blockchain transaction - not some service transaction