# Using SmartContract send ether to multiAddress with single Transaction But it is not getting ether in multiAccount

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3js, parity, ropsten

I have used already generated Contract Address: https://etherscan.io/address/0xb59fdff77a6175dfa4fe7af4281a52f61611eaa2#code

And using this I have created below Code:

```
// Include the packages
const Web3 = require('web3')
//const abi = require('human-standard-token-abi')
var abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenAddr","type":"address"},{"name":"dests","type":"address[]"},{"name":"values","type":"uint256[]"}],"name":"multisend","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"}];




// Set up Infura as your RPC connection
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));


// Define the contract addresses and the contract instance
const contractAddress = '0xb59fDfF77a6175DFA4fE7aF4281a52f61611eAa2'
//const contract = new web3.eth.contract(abi, contractAddress)

var contractAbi = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var contract = contractAbi.at(contractAddress);
// suppose you want to call a function named myFunction of myContract




fetch('http://localhost:8545', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 'method': 'personal_unlockAccount', 'params': ["0x2885f9904f3d1790ba53009bc9e0baae377d67df","kiranmalvi",null], 'id': 1, 'jsonrpc': '2.0' }) })
    .then(function (res) {


        contract.multisend.sendTransaction('0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57',["0x2885f9904f3d1790ba53009bc9e0baae377d67df","0x7b7cd7d5cee9fb36b7995a3d81df0122a0b1af4a"],["100","200"],{
            from:"0x2885f9904f3d1790ba53009bc9e0baae377d67df",
            gas:4000000 },function (error, result){
            if(!error){
                console.log(result);
            } else{
                console.log(error);
            }
        })

    });
```

But Transaction are not distributing multi address which I defined It is only send all amount in contract address. Can you help me What should I do for it?

Comment: Are "multiAddress" and "multiAccount" terms you've seen used before? If so, where? If not, please refrain from using non-standard terms. They make it hard for people to understand your questions.

Comment: And it sounds like you need help with a smart contract, but you haven't included the code for that contract.

Comment: I already shared smartContact code: https://etherscan.io/address/0xb59fdff77a6175dfa4fe7af4281a52f61611eaa2#code

Comment: Discussion about the same 'multiaddress' terminology problems: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41212/is-it-possible-send-from-multiaddress-using-single-transaction-without-contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace the fetch part like this.

```
web3local.personal.unlockAccount(addr, pass);
tokenlocal.multisend(tokenAddress,["0x2885f9904f3d1790ba53009bc9e0baae377d67df","0x7b7cd7d5cee9fb36b7995a3d81df0122a0b1af4a"],["100","200"], { from: addr }, function (err, txHash) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
  if (txHash) {
    console.log(txHash)
  }
})
```

**Edit**
Just checked your code. Few points to note.

- You are not sending ETH but sending the tokens
- You are not converting the number of tokens to its base unit value. e.g., if the number of decimals of your token is 5, when you send 10 tokens, it would be considered as 0.00010. You may have to change your smart contract for this.